# Pandas group by rows selection based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select the row within pandas group by based on condition.

- Condition1 # For a given group R1,R2,W, if TYPE(A) amount2 is equal to TYPE(B) row, we need to bring the complete TYPE(A) row as output.
- Condition2 # For a given group R1,R2,W, if TYPE(A) row amount2 is not equal to  TYPE(B) row amount2 , we need sum up the amount1 & amount2 of both TYPE (A) & (B) rows & we need to bring the remaining columns from the TYPE(A) row as output.

Input dataframe

```
    R1  R2  W   TYPE amount1 amount2 Status Exchange
0   123 12  1   A   111      222         C      1.5
1   123 12  1   B   111      222         D      2.5
2   123 12  2   A   222      222         A      1.5
3   123 12  2   B   333      333         D      2.5
4   123 12  3   A   444      444         D      2.5
5   123 12  3   B   333      333         E      3.5
```

Expected output

```
    R1  R2  W   TYPE amount1 amount2 Status Exchange
0   123 12  1   A   111      222         C      1.5
1   123 12  2   A   555      555         A      1.5
2   123 12  3   A   777      777         D      2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is necessary get all groups with `amount1` equal by `amount2` by reshape with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), compare selected columns by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and for test if all columns match is used [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for same length like original:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['R1','R2','W','TYPE'])['amount2'].unstack()
m = df1['A'].eq(df1['B']).rename('m')
m = df.join(m, on=['R1','R2','W'])['m']
```

Then for match rows (here first group) filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only `A` rows chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df2 = df[m & df['TYPE'].eq('A')]
print (df2)
    R1  R2  W TYPE  amount1  amount2 Status  Exchange
0  123  12  1    A      111      222      C       1.5
```

Then filter all another groups by inverted mask with `~` and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) all columns with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and `amount` columns by `sum`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['R1','R2','W','amount1','amount2'])
d1 = dict.fromkeys(['amount1','amount2'], 'sum')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(cols, 'first')

df3 = df[~m].groupby(['R1','R2','W'], as_index=False).agg({**d1, **d2}).assign(TYPE='A')
print (df3)
    R1  R2  W  amount1  amount2  Exchange Status TYPE
0  123  12  2      555      555       1.5      A    A
1  123  12  3      777      777       2.5      D    A
```

Last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and if necessary sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], ignore_index=True, sort=False).sort_values(['R1','R2','W'])
print (df4)
    R1  R2  W TYPE  amount1  amount2 Status  Exchange
0  123  12  1    A      111      222      C       1.5
1  123  12  2    A      555      555      A       1.5
2  123  12  3    A      777      777      D       2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hi I just started checking on it and realized that there is slight change in my initial question, i just updated the main question now. Only we need to check the amount2 of Row type(A) is not equal to amount2  of Type(B) .i see there should be slight change in your solution aswell, please suggest

Comment: @ramk - answer was edited, you can change [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60798550/revisions)

Comment: @ jezrael -working as expected on sample set data . thanks for your speedy support.will apply on full set of production data and let you know the outcome asap .Thanks again for your kind and timely support.appreciate

Comment: I have posted one new question.can you please let us know feedback.[Pandas Dataframe Derive the new calculated columns based on existing input columns (refer the current and prevous row without using loop)]

Comment: For sure .I will do the same

Comment: Kindly let me know the option where I can accept.i am new to this site.kindly advise

Comment: Done.is it reflecting ?

Comment: @ramk - Yes, thank you. Now I check your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
#get the rows for A for each grouping
#assumption is TYPE is already sorted with A always ahead of B
core = ['R1','R2','W']
A = df.groupby(core).first()

#get rows for B for each grouping
B = df.groupby(core).last()

#first condition
cond1 = (A.amount1.eq(B.amount1)) & (A.amount2.eq(B.amount2))

#extract outcome from A to get the first part
part1 = A.loc[cond1]

#second condition
cond2 = A.amount2.ne(B.amount2)

#add the 'amount1' and 'amount 2' columns based on the second condition
part2 = B.loc[cond2].filter(['amount1','amount2']) + 
A.loc[cond2].filter(['amount1','amount2'])


#merge with A to get the remaining columns
part2 = part2.join(A[['TYPE','Status','Exchange']])

#merge part1 and 2 to get final result
pd.concat([part1,part2]).reset_index()


     R1 R2  W   TYPE    amount1 amount2 Status  Exchange
0   123 12  1   A        111    222         C   1.5
1   123 12  2   A        555    555         A   1.5
2   123 12  3   A        777    777         D   2.5
```

Comment: Hi Sammywemmy - thanks for the update,  there is slight change in my initial question, i just updated the main question now. Only we need to check the amount2 of Row type(A) is not equal to amount2 of Type(B) .

Comment: Hi, I have edited and made necessary changes, and am getting error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" during execution of '#add the 'amount1' and 'amount 2' columns based on the second condition
part2 = B.loc[cond2].filter(['amount1','amount2']) + 
A.loc[cond2].filter(['amount1','amount2'])'

Comment: i just retried it and it works on my end. check the lines for each of them individually and see if u can isolate the error. Also, try jezrael's solution which should work as well.

Comment: Issue is at my end and after the fix it is working as expected and thanks for your speedy support.will apply on fill set of production data and let you know the outcome asap .Thanks again

Comment: I have posted one new question.can you please let us know feedback.Pandas Dataframe Derive the new calculated columns based on existing input columns (refer the current and prevous row without using loop)